# Slow access to encrypted files over LAN in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, encryption, efs

I have two computers in my home network, connected to the same wireless access point, let's call them Desktop and Laptop.

Desktop shares all of its disks over network (enabled by right-clicking the disk in the Explorer and chosing "Share").

Laptop can access files shared by the Desktop, with one caveat - if the files are encrypted (by right clicking on the parent folder and going to "Advanced..." -> "Encrypt contents to secure data"), then the access time is very slow. For example, if on Laptop I navigate to an encrypted folder shared by Desktop and double click an image file to open it, it takes about 30s to show on my screen. It does not happen in case of non-encrypted files. Moreover, if I access network share on Desktop through my Android phone, the access is instanteous.

Both computers use Windows 10 Pro.

What might be the cause of this issue and how I can mitigate it?

EDIT: The same sloweness is encountered when an encrypted file on Laptop is accessed using the Desktop.

EDIT2: Funny thing, on Laptop, if I use WSL2, mount Windows share there using `mount -t cifs ...` the files open instantly as well (for example using eog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution [on this forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec828640-410f-4e2a-b30a-96c526591ee5/slow-file-access-on-encrypted-files?forum=win10itprosecurity). One has to enable "Remote Service Management (RPC)" rule for the current network profile on Windows Defender Firewall.